# UITableViewCell Data should load to other ViewController

Tags: ios, tableview

I am using TableViewCell in my application. and the cell data like label text and image from imageview at perticular cell. should view in next view controller.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MainBodyViewController * mainViewController =[[MainBodyViewController alloc]init];
    MasterDetails * masted =(MasterDetails*)[listArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"did select row at index is givne as:%@",masted);
    mainViewController.headLbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",masted.title];
}
```

But the problem is I am not getting data from listArray. The data coming from json.

Comment: yes. i want to pass cell data like . label text and image for particular cell selected.the selected cell data should appear in next viewcontroller on label and text .

Comment: show your tableview delegate methods

Comment: delegate methods and data source are same. i mean we use it as delegate methods and data source as self

Comment: i checked it and i am using those methods but i am getting error if i use those . if you get any then please send me link for that one.

Comment: had you check this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers

Comment: no , i didnt .  i will check it out. lets see if its work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check

1. Table view No of rows should be [listarry count] to avoid out of
   index.
2. "MasterDetails" object is created properly, as per no of cell == json parsed object.
3. "listarray" is allocated.